# Pandas group by time windows

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT: [Session generation from log file analysis with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547391/session-generation-from-log-file-analysis-with-pandas) seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

I have a dataframe that includes non-unique time stamps, and I'd like to group them by time windows.  The basic logic would be -

1) Create a time range from each time stamp by adding n minutes before and after the time stamp.

2) Group by time ranges that overlap.  The end effect here would be that a time window would be as small as a single time stamp +/- the time buffer, but there is no cap on how large a time window could be, as long as multiple events were less distance apart than the time buffer

It feels like a df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(minutes=n)) is the right answer, but I don't know how to have the TimeGrouper create dynamic time ranges when it sees events that are within a time buffer.

For instance, if I try a TimeGrouper('20s') against a set of events: 10:34:00, 10:34:08, 10:34:08, 10:34:15, 10:34:28 and 10:34:54, then pandas will give me three groups (events falling between 10:34:00 - 10:34:20, 10:34:20 - 10:34:40, and 10:34:40-10:35:00).  I would like to just get two groups back, 10:34:00 - 10:34:28, since there is no more than a 20 second gap between events in that time range, and a second group that is 10:34:54.

What is the best way to find temporal windows that are not static bins of time ranges?

Given a Series that looks something like -

```
      time
0     2013-01-01 10:34:00+00:00
1     2013-01-01 10:34:12+00:00
2     2013-01-01 10:34:28+00:00
3     2013-01-01 10:34:54+00:00
4     2013-01-01 10:34:55+00:00
5     2013-01-01 10:35:19+00:00
6     2013-01-01 10:35:30+00:00
```

If I do a df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('20s')) on that Series, I would get back 5 group, 10:34:00-:20, :20-:40, :40-10:35:00, etc.  What I want to do is have some function that creates elastic timeranges.. as long as events are within 20 seconds, expand the timerange.  So I expect to get back -

```
2013-01-01 10:34:00 - 2013-01-01 10:34:48 
    0 2013-01-01 10:34:00+00:00
    1 2013-01-01 10:34:12+00:00
    2 2013-01-01 10:34:28+00:00

2013-01-01 10:34:54 - 2013-01-01 10:35:15
    3 2013-01-01 10:34:54+00:00
    4 2013-01-01 10:34:55+00:00

2013-01-01 10:35:19 - 2013-01-01 10:35:50
    5 2013-01-01 10:35:19+00:00
    6 2013-01-01 10:35:30+00:00
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how to use to create a custom grouper. (requires pandas >= 0.13) for the timedelta computations, but otherwise would work in other versions.

Create your series

```
In [31]: s = Series(range(6),pd.to_datetime(['20130101 10:34','20130101 10:34:08', '20130101 10:34:08', '20130101 10:34:15', '20130101 10:34:28', '20130101 10:34:54','20130101 10:34:55','20130101 10:35:12']))

In [32]: s
Out[32]: 
2013-01-01 10:34:00    0
2013-01-01 10:34:08    1
2013-01-01 10:34:08    2
2013-01-01 10:34:15    3
2013-01-01 10:34:28    4
2013-01-01 10:34:54    5
2013-01-01 10:34:55    6
2013-01-01 10:35:12    7
dtype: int64
```

This just computes the time difference in seconds between successive elements, but could actually be anything

```
In [33]: indexer = s.index.to_series().order().diff().fillna(0).astype('timedelta64[s]')

In [34]: indexer
Out[34]: 
2013-01-01 10:34:00     0
2013-01-01 10:34:08     8
2013-01-01 10:34:08     0
2013-01-01 10:34:15     7
2013-01-01 10:34:28    13
2013-01-01 10:34:54    26
2013-01-01 10:34:55     1
2013-01-01 10:35:12    17
dtype: float64
```

Arbitrariy assign things < 20s to group 0, else to group 1. This could also be more arbitrary. if the diff from previous is < 0 BUT the total diff (from first) is > 50 make in group 2.

```
In [35]: grouper = indexer.copy()

In [36]: grouper[indexer<20] = 0

In [37]: grouper[indexer>20] = 1

In [95]: grouper[(indexer<20) & (indexer.cumsum()>50)] = 2

In [96]: grouper
Out[96]: 
2013-01-01 10:34:00    0
2013-01-01 10:34:08    0
2013-01-01 10:34:08    0
2013-01-01 10:34:15    0
2013-01-01 10:34:28    0
2013-01-01 10:34:54    1
2013-01-01 10:34:55    2
2013-01-01 10:35:12    2
dtype: float64
```

Groupem (can also use an apply here)

```
In [97]: s.groupby(grouper).sum()
Out[97]: 
0    10
1     5
2    13
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Jeff, I definitely like where you're going with this.  I'm not sure how to take that out to scale though.  What if you add in two more events at 2013-01-01 10:34:55 and 10:35:12.  You'd end up with the indexer dataframe having two more lines:

2013-01-01 10:34:55    1,
2013-01-01 10:35:12    17

and then both of those would end up in the [indexer < 20] group.

Comment: The indexer could be as big as the original series if you want. I'll update the example to do what I think you want.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jeff.  In your groups now though, you have three groups when you should really just have two (10:34:00 - 10:34:28 and 10:34:54 - 10:35:12).

Comment: This is just an example, I am not sure what you want. You could easily have a function do this if you want. Just create the grouper like you want.

Comment: What I would like to do is to create a window id for each time range that is created by identifying those overlapping events.  In your example (grouper dataframe), you end up with 10:34:54 as a different number than 10:34:55 and 10:35:12.   Maybe I'm framing the question wrong by focusing on pandas, and this is really a question of "what's the best way to create elastic ranges of overlapping events in python".  I had hoped pandas had a sort of built in TimeSeries manipulation function in here already.

Comment: still not sure what you are asking, maybe put up a very explicit question. Or better yet show what you are expecting as a result.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the confusion Jeff.  I've edited my original post, may do some more edits.  It's a bit of a pain since I don't have an interpreter on this computer to just copy/paste code.

Answer (score 1):

You might want consider using [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
def my_grouper(datetime_value):
    return some_group(datetime_value)

df.groupby(df['date_time'].apply(my_grouper))
```

It's up to you to implement just any grouping logic in your grouper function. Btw, merging overlapping time ranges is kind of iterative task: for example, A = (0, 10), B = (20, 30), C = (10, 20). After C appears, all three, A, B and C should be merged.

**UPD:**

This is my ugly version of merging algorithm:

```
groups = {}

def in_range(val, begin, end):
    return begin <= val <= end

global max_group_id
max_group_id = 1

def find_merged_group(begin, end):
    global max_group_id
    found_common_group = None
    full_wraps = []

    for (group_start, group_end), group in groups.iteritems():
        begin_inclusion = in_range(begin, group_start, group_end)
        end_inclusion = in_range(end, group_start, group_end)
        full_inclusion = begin_inclusion and end_inclusion
        full_wrap = not begin_inclusion and not end_inclusion and in_range(group_start, begin, end) and in_range(group_end, begin, end)
        if full_inclusion:
            groups[(begin, end)] = group
            return group
        if full_wrap:
            full_wraps.append(group)
        elif begin_inclusion or end_inclusion:
            if not found_common_group:
                 found_common_group = group
            else:  # merge
                for range, g in groups.iteritems():
                    if g == group:
                        groups[range] = found_common_group

    if not found_common_group:
        found_common_group = max_group_id
        max_group_id += 1
    groups[(begin, end)] = found_common_group
    return found_common_group

def my_grouper(date_time):
    return find_merged_group(date_time - 1, date_time + 1)

df['datetime'].apply(my_grouper) # first run to fill groups dict
grouped = df.groupby(df['datetime'].apply(my_grouper))  # this run is using already merged groups
```

Comment: Muzhig, thanks for the response!  I'm not sure how the logic plays out in the my_grouper function though.  Can you show me an example of what my_grouper would look like if you were just finding overlapping tuples (as your A, B, and C are in your post)?

Comment: Updated the code. Well... it doesn't look very elegant :)

Comment: Muzhig, I appreciate the example!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

- create a column `tsdiff` that has the diffs between consecutive times (using `shift`)
- `df['new_group'] = df.tsdiff > timedelta`
- `fillna` on the `new_group`
- `groupby` that column

this is just really rough pseudocode, but the solution's in there somewhere...