# Bin column by time intervals and calculate the sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the pandas DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "computer": [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
    "time":     [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "value":    [4, 1, 5, 6, 1, 0, 3, 4],
})
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit="s")
df.set_index(["computer", "time"])
```

I would like to bin `time` column into 4s intervals and sum the `value`s.
The output would look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "computer":   [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3],
    "start_time": [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4],
    "value":      [5, 1, 5, 6, 3, 4],
})
df["start_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_time"], unit="s")
df.set_index(["computer", "start_time"])
```

I've tried to apply the code provided by [Pandas group by time windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769047), but I'm unable to get it working due to the multiindex.
I've also tried the `resample` method, but the same problem applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `pd.Grouper`:

```
u = (df.groupby(['computer', pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='4s')])
       .sum()
       .sort_index(level=1)
       .reset_index())
u['time'] = u['time'].dt.second

u
   computer  time  value
0         0     0      5
1         1     0      1
2         2     0      5
3         3     0      6
4         2     4      3
5         3     4      4
```

Instead of having a separate `groupby` and `resample`, you can allow one `groupby` call to handle both the grouping on "computer", and the resampling "time" together.

Answer (score 1):

Use, `reset_index`, then `groupby` and `resample`:

```
df.reset_index(level=0).groupby('computer').resample('4s')['value']\
   .sum().to_frame().sort_index(level=1)
```

OR

```
df.reset_index('computer').groupby('computer').resample('4s')['value']\
   .sum().to_frame().sort_index(level=1)
```

Output:

```
                              value
computer time                      
0        1970-01-01 00:00:00      5
1        1970-01-01 00:00:00      1
2        1970-01-01 00:00:00      5
3        1970-01-01 00:00:00      6
2        1970-01-01 00:00:04      3
3        1970-01-01 00:00:04      4
```